# MS SQL - Minimum Permissions to View Sensitivity Classifications

Tags: permissions

I'd like to provide some user groups access to view Sensitivity Classifications. Currently it returns blank results in the reports tool, or directly querying sys.sensitivity_classifications table.

What's the minimum permission set, default or custom, which could be used to provide a read only view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sensitivity-classifications-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#permissions

Requires the VIEW ANY SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION permission.

Comment: Thanks, didn’t see when searching before, perhaps not appearing in my SSMS as older version, will try granting directly, assume will work based on that info.